# "Simply Javascript" Question

Tags: javascript

Im new to javascript.  I've been learning for about a month and am currently reading the Simply Javascript book by Kevin Yank and Cameron Adams.

The fist few chapters started out really well but the book got really difficult in the chapter about events.  They go on about the problems with events listeners and say here just use these functions we made to make it easier.

Im just wondering whether this is good advice should I just use their functions without really understanding how they are working, and should just try and plug through this chapter and hope that the next topics are a bit easier to understand.

If anyone has some other advice on where to start learning or some exercises I could do that would be great aswell.

Thanks

Comment: For the book it is probably better to go with these functions. However if you want to learn more about event handling (which you should if you really want to understand it. It is not such a complex topic, it is only annoying that different browsers do different things.), read this: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a moment and try to understand what they're saying. If you have a specific question, ask it here. There is plenty of material on the web about why you need to be careful with events and listeners.

If you *really* do want to ignore the issue for now, I suggest using a framework like [jQuery](http://jquery.com). At the very least, you can dive into how *they* work through the issues.

But, just moving on and coming back to the chapter later might make it easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use their code, plough on with the rest of the book, then come back to that chapter.

Event handling in JavaScript is a nightmare, and they're quite right to wrap it up in some helper functions (most people in the real world use jQuery or a similar toolkit for this).

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I have a book. I write everything down in a way that I understand it.. If not I review it and write it in a way I understand it, and so I can remember I also challenge myself with questions I make up to try and remember, because I have a terrible memory.. If you still don't understand try W3 Schools they explain everything in detail and they have Examples and problems to solve at the end, if you don't get it you can also see the answer and try to figure it out. CodeCademy and CodeSchool is also a great way to learn interactively, it is also free. You can buy an advanced edition for a decent price and it will go through EVERYTHING I think it has a chat to so someone can teach you.